# Sending ASCII from C# to Arduino using Bluetooth

Tags: c#, bluetooth, arduino

I am trying to interface my C# [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application from my laptop to the Arduino [Duemilanove](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDuemilanove). A Bluetooth module is connected to the Tx and Rx pins on the Arduino. My goal is to light up the on-board LED when I type in the letter 'a' and so far it has been unsuccessful. I am sure the Bluetooth is connected with my laptop, but it is not responding to the letter I am pressing.

#### C# code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Guid service = BluetoothService.SerialPort;
    private BluetoothClient bluetoothClient;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Form1_KeyPress);
    }

    void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 'a')
        {
            Stream peerStream = bluetoothClient.GetStream();
            Byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("a");
            peerStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }

    private void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode = RadioMode.Discoverable;
        BluetoothRadio myRadio = BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio;
        bluetoothClient = new BluetoothClient();
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        BluetoothDeviceInfo[] bluetoothDeviceInfo = { };
        bluetoothDeviceInfo = bluetoothClient.DiscoverDevices(10);
        comboBox1.DataSource = bluetoothDeviceInfo;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "DeviceName";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "DeviceAddress";
        comboBox1.Focus();
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }

    private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            try
            {
                bluetoothClient.Connect(new BluetoothEndPoint((BluetoothAddress)comboBox1.SelectedValue, service));
                MessageBox.Show("Connected");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Arduino Code

```
int incomingByte = 0;   // For incoming serial data
void setup()
{
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT); // On-board LED as output
    Serial.begin(9600);     // Opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bit/s.
}

void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        // Read the incoming byte:
        incomingByte = Serial.read();

        if (incomingByte == 'a')
            digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    }
}
```

Am I sending the ASCII code wrongly or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

May be the same issue as I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10902704/1440715).

> I recently dabbled into this. The Arduino automatically resets when it
> receives serial communication from most things other than the Arduino
> IDE. This is why you can send from the IDE but not node.js.
>
> I have an Uno and put a capacitor between Reset and Ground.Here's a
> page with some good info on the subject. Good luck.
> http://arduino.cc/playground/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection