# Sending data to Arduino Uno with Java

Tags: java, arduino

I have just bought an Arduino Uno and I am currently trying to make a flashing LED. I was wondering how I could do this, and I have looked at the Arduino Playground and have found a program to get input. I need to output to the Arduino. It is not possible for me to use anything but Java because I already have another program that requires an Arduino. Please leave any ideas.

Comment: Have you checked http://arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Java ?

Comment: Yes, that is the website I saw. But that only has information on getting input, I want to output.

Comment: I'm confused?  You want to control the flashing led via your computer to the arduino using java?  Or do you want a Java development environment?  Please explain what your trying to do and how your doing it.

Comment: I want to control the flashing led connected to the Arduino with Java. The Arduino IDE is not an option because I already have another java program I am going to use the Arduino for.

Comment: @jayeff  +1 for good suggestion.  You are correct.  I quoted you in my answer below.  Post it as an answer and I'll +1 it. OP should select that as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**  Kind of sounds like you want to do this in java.

And excerpt from the [site](http://arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Java) mentioned by [jayeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1458461/jayeff):

> The OutputStream comes with 3 different write methods to send data
>   from the computer to the Arduino. In the above example, you could use
>   **`output.write(String)`** to send data, as in **`output.write("Hello
>   Arduino!")`**.

If you're trying to use Java to write to the Arduino, then this is your answer.

http://arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Java

---

**EDIT**: If you want to use something other than Java, here you go:

Ask and you shall receive.  You can do this in any programming language that has serial support.

There are certainly other methods for each language, but here are some I found in 5 minutes at the Google Machine

- **Perl** - [Device::SerialPort](http://search.cpan.org/~cook/Device-SerialPort-1.002/SerialPort.pm)
- **Python** - [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) via [Android Playground](http://arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Python)
- **C++** - [LibSerial](http://libserial.sourceforge.net/) (used below)

**Note:** Watch out for the nasty [Auto Reset on Serial](http://arduino.cc/playground/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection) issue.  See my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10921900/1440715) for more details on that.

**Here's my C++ Code (it's ugly but it works)**

```cpp
#include <SerialStream.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
class SerialComm {
    LibSerial::SerialStream myss;
public:

    SerialComm(int argc, char** argv) {
        myss = new LibSerial::SerialStream("/dev/ttyS0", ios_base::out);
        myss.SetBaudRate(LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::BAUD_57600);
        myss.SetCharSize(LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::CHAR_SIZE_8);
        myss.SetFlowControl(LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::FLOW_CONTROL_NONE);
        myss.SetParity(LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::PARITY_NONE);
        myss.SetNumOfStopBits(1);

        const int Dsize = 2;
        char buffer[1];
        buffer[0] = 125; //0b00000001;
        buffer[1] = '\0';
        bitset(buffer[0]);
        //myss << buffer;
        myss.write(buffer,1);
        //myss.Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This was a good idea but I did it a different way by making the arduino output for the amount of milliseconds that I write to the serial port.