# Clear data in Serial.read()

Tags: c++, arduino

I am programming an Arduino to turn a LED on when it receives something in the serial port. I have done this and it has received the data but after the LED should have been turned off it keeps going. Here is my current code:

```
int ledPin = 13;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.print("RECEIVED_CALL");
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(4500);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    Serial.clear();
  }
}
```

Please leave any suggestions.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have a 4500 ms i.e. 4.5 second delay? Also if you still have data available it will be turned right back on. Try adding a delay after you set the pin low

Comment: 1. I need it on for 4.5 seconds
2. I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Add some debugging statements (like `Serial.print("LED_OFF")`) to be sure that your Arduino is not restarting upon receiving serial data as described in my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10921900/1440715).

This may account for the light staying on.  It may be restarting over and over again if you are sending enough serial data.