# Re-connecting to serial port after a disconnection

Tags: java, serial-port, arduino, jfreechart

Hey I'm doing a program where I read in serial data and display it on a graph.  I have two files in my java project: one that takes care of the graph display and the other solely for serial processing.  One of the requirements for this program is to have my arduino sending data get disconnected, show a message on the graph, re-connect the arduino, then have that message disappear and have the data being sent again without user interaction.  I have my serial file down below.  I'm not sure how I can edit it to see that it has been disconnected from the PC, then reconnect without human interaction.  Thanks

```
public class SerialTest implements SerialPortEventListener {
SerialPort serialPort;
private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 

        "COM11", // Windows
};
String turnon = "X";
String inputLine;
String temp;
String temp1;
String thirdDC;
static boolean deviceConn;

int value = 0;
int count;
String stop = "STOP";
String y = "Y";
String z = "Z";
String pop;
Double x;
int n;
int working;
private BufferedReader input;
/** The output stream to the port */
OutputStream output;
/** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
/** Default bits per second for COM port. */
private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

public void initialize() {
    working = 1;
    CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
    Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
        for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
            if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                portId = currPortId;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (portId == null) {
        thirdDC = "Could not find COM Port. Error";
        System.out.println(thirdDC);

        return;
    }

    try {

        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                TIME_OUT);

        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
        output = serialPort.getOutputStream();


        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString() + "BLAHHHHH");
    }
}


public synchronized void close() {
    if (serialPort != null) {
        serialPort.removeEventListener();
        serialPort.close();
    }
}

public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    String stop = "ERROR";
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        deviceConn = true;
        try {

            inputLine=input.readLine();
            if (inputLine.equals(y)){
                System.out.println(y);
                temp1 = "OFF";
                value = 0;
            }
            if (inputLine.equals(z)){
                System.out.println(z);
                temp1 = "ON";
                value = 0;
            }
            if (inputLine.equals(stop)){
                System.out.println(stop);
                temp = "ERROR";
                value = 1;  
            }


            x = Double.parseDouble(inputLine);
            if (x > 0){
            temp = inputLine;
            System.out.println(x);
            value = 0;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {                             
        }
    }           
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Thread t=new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
        } 
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
        }
    };
    t.start();
    System.out.println("Started");
}
}
```

Comment: If there is the disconnect, is there an exception? Then you could catch it and handle a reconnect and call an event for your graph.

Comment: @jpee, thanks.  I am just having trouble figuring out where in the code it shows that it disconnects.  Does that make sense?  I feel if I find out in the code where it disconnects, I could have it print a message to the screen and right under that line of code, just call initialize() again.  Is that the right idea?

Comment: Sounds good, not sure if all of initialize method is needed. Maybe a connect method could be created which will be called from the initialize and exception handling.

Comment: Would it be anything like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571498/reconnect-serial-port-on-processing) example?  I am trying to follow it but really get 100% on parts of my program relate to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) of a Client/Server implementation using sockets and this simple client sever chat program also using [sockets](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/chat-client-server.html).

Put your `SerialPortEventListener` on the server site and the chart on the client side. You will need to communicate asynchronously, the sever shold broadcast the message to all clients rather then using two way communication.

Implement you solution using two separate main classes and you will be able to stop and restart eitehr part at will.